# Why do I get an error "Too many }'s" when using package doublespace?

Tags: packages, errors

When I use pdfLaTeX to compile this document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{doublespace}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{foo1.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

> [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version
>   2006.09.02).] )   ! Too many }'s.
>   \color@endbox ->\color@endgroup
>   \egroup 
>                                            l.10 \end{figure}
>                     ?

Can anyone tell me how I can avoid this?

P.S. I removed the complete stdout, which can be found by looking at previous edits; I can re-post if it contains pertinent information

*update*

The error does not seem to be that I did not use graphicx, when I got rid of files from previous. compilations, the error when graphicx is not included is:

> No file foo.aux. ! Undefined control
>   sequence. 
>   \includegraphics 
>                                     l.8 \includegraphics
>                       [width=0.5\textwidth]{foo1.pdf}

I have changed the example file to include what is required to make the compilation fail when the document is run from a directory that is empty of files (like foo.aux) produced by previous pdflatex compilations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You did not load the graphicx package, though you're using `\includegraphics`. That's why the compilation should fail.

Regarding doublespace, this package is obsolete, it has serious bugs as the [description on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/doublespace) says. Better use [setspace](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) instead.

Comment: setspace solved the issue.